# How to solve logarithmic function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am still confused with my solution about Logarithmic function. Does anyone know how to solve this? Do you have links about logarithm in connection to this problem? thank you

$$4\log_2 x - 2\log_2 y = \log_2 9$$

Comment: What do you mean by "solve"? You have one equation, two variables --- you're not going to get values for both --- do you mean "simplify"? or, express $y$ in terms of $x$? or something else...?

Comment: Solve for y in terms of x.

Comment: Good. So: what is stopping you? Can you make a start on the problem? How does one usually start, when trying to solve for $y$?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

$$\log |x^y| = y\log |x|$$

and

$$\log |x/y| = \log |x| - \log |y|$$

Since your dealing with base 2, it should be relatively easy if you give it some thought. Can you finish the steps from here?